# Number of objects created when a StringBuilder is initialized

Tags: java, string

Would this line create two objects, one String object for the literal "Hello" and one StringBuilder object, or would it create just the one StringBuilder object?

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");`

If it creates two objects, will the string object be interned?

Comment: As I understand it, all string literals are interned. Which means whether one or two objects are created by your line of code, ignoring any objects created as part of the implementations of `StringBuilder` and `String`, depends on if `"Hello"` was previously interned or not.

Comment: @slaw I was given to understand that StringBuilder has the advantage of avoiding interning of temporary Strings. If its constructor and append which I assume works the same way needs a preexisting String object for initialization, wouldn't that defeat one of the advantages of the StringBuilder?

Comment: Don't forget that a `StringBuilder` has internal objects.

Comment: Assume Java does the smart thing.  You'll be correct.

Comment: One object is created, the `StringBuilder`, and whatever is inside it, which isn't specified. The string literal was pooled by the compiler and created as an object when the class was loaded.

Comment: A `String` you **build** with `StringBuilder` won't be interned. But you're passing a `String` to the constructor of `StringBuilder`, which means the `String` object must exist before the constructor can be called. You created that `String` using a string literal, so it's interned. As noted above, however, literals are apparently instantiated and interned at class-loading time.

Comment: The open jdk code for the base class that implements most of stringbuilder is [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java). You can see that internally, characters are held in an array that's grown as needed.  The code - as others have said - will use the string literal created at compile time. That will be copied into the string builder's internal character array at construction time. So there will be two objects created when your code runs: the stringbuilder and its internal array of chars, not the literal itself.

Comment: I suggest one of you turn those Comments into an Answer.